# Phoenix Application 'posts' Show Newest First

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my Phoenix application I have a model called 'posts'.

Here's the relevant controller action:

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    posts = Repo.all(Post)
    render(conn, "index.html", posts: posts)
  end
```

The problem is - this displays all posts starting with the oldest one. What I would like is to show all posts starting with the newest one (oldest one appears last).

How can I modify the controller to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add an `order_by` statement to your query.

Comment: please explain how to add an order_by statement to the query

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#order_by/3).

Comment: Thanks - I've read the documentation; however, the documentation doesn't tell me how to apply this to my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use [`order_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#order_by/3).

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  posts = Repo.all(from Post, order_by: [desc: :inserted_at])
  render(conn, "index.html", posts: posts)
end
```

Comment: This does not put the posts in the order that I want. I'm not sure why it's not working - it is not providing any error messages. The posts are in the same order they were when I asked the question (oldest first). I tried changing it to `asc:` instead of `desc` and it had the same effect.

Comment: ha, good catch. Let me make an edit. But it basically becomes what you have.

Comment: Works now - thank you! A little cleaner than the solution I posted above so I will accept thing. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution I came up with from the documentation. If anyone can come up with a cleaner solution please let me know.

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    posts = Repo.all(from(p in Post, order_by: [desc: :inserted_at]))
    render(conn, "index.html", posts: posts)
  end
```